# Menus disappeared after upgrade

Tags: 16.04, menu

I recently updated to Ubuntu 16.04. Since then, I've noticed that the menus (File, Edit, View etc.) have disappeared for some applications and not for others. Chrome for instance still has it's menus, but Geany(an IDE) and Shutter(a screengrab program) do not. Nautilus doesn't either. It's not a case of turning them on in the settings as that makes no difference. I did come across a forum a while ago instructing to delete a couple of libs, which worked, until I updated Ubuntu the other day. I can't find that forum again. I remember the libs had something to do with qt I think... Can anyone help me?